# Dot and Square Bracket Notation

Tags: javascript, syntax, square-bracket

I'm trying to understand the difference between the Dot and the Square Bracket Notation. While going through various examples here on SO and on some other sites, I came across these two simple examples:

```js
var obj = { "abc" : "hello" };
var x = "abc";
var y = obj[x];
console.log(y); //output - hello
```

```js
var user = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 30
};
var key = prompt("Enter the property to modify","name or age");
var value = prompt("Enter new value for " + key);
user[key] = value;
alert("New " + key + ": " + user[key]);
```

The first example returns y to be undefined if in third line I replace the `obj[x]` with `obj.x`. Why not `"hello"`

---

But in the second example the expression `user[key]` can simply be replaced with `user.key` without any anomalous behavior (at-least to me).
Now this confuses me as I recently learned that if we want to access properties by name stored in a variable, we use the [ ] Square bracket Notation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: Look at the *whole* object, not just the property you modified.

Comment: `obj.key` means the property `key` (literally) of `obj`. `obj[key]` means the property whose key is stored in variable `key` of `obj`. There’s a clear difference. Using `obj.key` overwrites the same property, so you can’t set a name and an age simultaneously. Just look at your object with `console.log(obj)`. `name` and `age` won’t have changed and you’ll have another meaningless property `key` which holds some number or some string.

Comment: @Xufox thanks for taking time. This line really helped me- "obj.key means the property key (literally) of obj. obj[key] means the property whose key is stored in variable key of obj."   Sometimes one overlooks very obvious things, unless someone guides and points them in the right way... so thanks a lot pal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In dot notation, the name after the dot is the name of the property being referenced. So:

```
var foo = "bar";
var obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };

console.log(obj.foo) // = 1, since the "foo" property of obj is 1,
                     //      independent of the variable foo
```

However, in square-bracket notation, the name of the property being referenced is the *value*  of whatever is in the square brackets:

```
var foo = "bar";
var obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };

console.log(obj[foo])   // = 2, since the value of the variable foo is "bar" and
                        //      the "bar" property of obj is 2

console.log(obj["foo"]) // = 1, since the value of the literal "foo" is "foo" and
                        //      the "foo" property of obj is 1
```

In other words, dot-notation `obj.foo` is always equivalent to `obj["foo"]`, while `obj[foo]` depends on the value of the variable `foo`.

---

In the specific case of your question, note the differences between dot notation and square-bracket notation:

```
// with dot notation
var obj = { name: "John Doe", age: 30 };
var key = "age";
var value = 60;

obj.key = value; // referencing the literal property "key"
console.log(obj) // = { name: "John Doe", age: 30, key: 60 }


// with square bracket notation
var obj = { name: "John Doe", age: 30 };
var key = "age";
var value = 60;

obj[key] = value; // referencing property by the value of the key variable ("age")
console.log(obj)  // = { name: "John Doe", age: 60 }
```

Comment: Hey Frxstrem, can't thank you enough, your examples and your explanation cleared all my doubts regarding this topic and it is such a relief now... :D Thanks a bunch...

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing/Creation** of properties from/in a JavaScript object can be done in two ways

1. Using *Dot* notation
2. Using *Square Bracket* notation

Whenever some property is not defined i.e. not present in the object and you try to access it, you will get `undefined` (obviously, because it's not there).

So, in the first example you are *accessing* a property and in the second example you are *creating* a property. Therefore, replacing the notation did not affect the code in the second example.

Comment: This line really helped me, "Whenever some property is not defined i.e. not present in the object and you try to access it, you will get undefined"