# JQuery How to get JSON value by key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to translate from JSON file by html attribute

get JSON value like translate attribute and "ed" key

> JSON FILE

```
{
"open" : [
    {
        "en": "Open",
        "ed": "Opened"
    }
],

"close" : [
    {
        "en": "Close",
        "ed": "Closed"
    }
]

}
```

> HTML

```
<p translate="open"></p>
```

> JQuery

```
var word = $("p");
var wordA = $("p").attr("translate"); // open

$.getJSON('language.json', function(data) {
        
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

        if (key === wordA) {
           word.html(val.ed);
           // result opened
         }

    });

});
```

Comment: Since `val` is an array, you'll need to get the first item. `val[0].ed`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dot and Square Bracket Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417664/dot-and-square-bracket-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found an answer

```
var word = $("p");
var wordA = $("p").attr("translate"); // open

$.getJSON('language.json', function(data) {
    
   $.each(data[wordA], function(key, val) {

       word.html(val.ed);

   });
});
```