# Split dates in array with dash (-) and take first number from split result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array with dates having format as a DD-MM-YYYY. I have to take only DD i.e. days from it and push in another array.

I am trying using split function to separate out it but not able to push into array.

```js
  let arrayData = ["15-07-2022", "18-07-2022", "20-07-2022"];
  
  let pushData = [];
        arrayData.map(x => (
            pushData.push(x.split('-'))
     ))
     
     //output should be [15,18,20]
```

Comment: `pushData.push(x.split('-')[0])`

Comment: Don't use push inside a map. map already returns an array. `pushData = arrayData.map(x => x.split('-')[0])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dot and Square Bracket Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417664/dot-and-square-bracket-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve the desired result. Note I use `+` to convert the string to numbers as shown in your expected output.

```js
let arrayData = ["15-07-2022", "18-07-2022", "20-07-2022"];
const result = arrayData.map((date) => +date.split('-')[0])
console.log(result)
```